# "Esa regla no (se?) aplica en esta promoción"

Tags: verbos, pronombres

Estoy resolviendo algunas ejercicios de gramática. En ellos se indica que la oración "Esa regla no aplica en esta promoción" es incorrecta, mientras que la oración "Esa regla no se aplica en esta promoción" es correcta.

Revisando el DLE de la RAE indican que el verbo [aplicar](https://dle.rae.es/aplicar) solo es pronominal cuando se refiere a "Poner esmero, diligencia y cuidado en ejecutar algo, especialmente en estudiar.", mientras que es transitivo cuando el verbo hace referencia a "Emplear, administrar o poner en práctica un conocimiento, medida o principio".

¿Alguien podría confirmar que es correcto utilizar el pronombre *se* en "Esa regla no se aplica en esta promoción"? O en caso contrario explicarme por qué es incorrecto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El verbo [aplicar](https://dle.rae.es/aplicar) con el significado

> 2. tr. Emplear, administrar o poner en práctica un conocimiento, medida o principio, a fin de obtener un determinado efecto o rendimiento en alguien o algo.

es un verbo **transitivo** (tr.). Esto quiere decir que se puede usar o bien en voz activa con un complemento directo:

- La empresa no aplica esa regla en esta promoción

o en voz pasiva, donde el complemento directo se convierte en el sujeto:

- Esa regla no es aplicada (por la empresa) en esta promoción

Otra forma de expresar lo mismo es usar la [pasiva refleja](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables), que utiliza el pronombre *se*:

- Esta regla no se aplica en esta promoción

Este *se* no es pronominal, sino que es un indicador de la voz pasiva.

La otra opción

- Esta regla no aplica en esta promoción

utiliza el verbo *aplicar* como un verbo intransitivo. Según el DLE, es correcta **en América**:

> 8. intr. Am. Tener validez o relevancia para algo. *La norma no aplica a las compras hechas en el extranjero.*

En mi experiencia, y como indica el DLE, en España se usa más la forma transitiva con *se*.